# problems handling padding while decrypting a file using OpenSSL BIO

Tags: c, encryption, openssl, segmentation-fault, padding

I am having problems dealing with padding, which was added to the file during encryption. I wrote a program in c, which uses the aes_256_cbc algorithm that encrypts a 128byte file, to which 16 bytes of padding is added. Now, when I go to perform decryption, I try to handle the padding to remove it, but running this program I get: segmentation fault.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <openssl/bio.h>
#include <openssl/evp.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>

#define INBUFSIZE 1024
#define OUTBUFSIZE (2 * INBUFSIZE)

void handleErrors(void) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Error occurred.\n");
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

int removePKCS7Padding(char *buffer, int block_size, int *data_size) {
    int padding_value = buffer[*data_size - 1];

    // Verifica che il padding sia corretto
    if (padding_value >= 1 && padding_value <= block_size) {
        *data_size -= padding_value;
        return 1; // Padding rimosso correttamente
    }

    return 0; // Padding non valido
}

void decryptAndWriteToFile(const char *inputFileName, const char *outputFileName) {
    BIO *inputBio = BIO_new_file(inputFileName, "rb");
    BIO *outputBio = BIO_new_file(outputFileName, "wb");

    if (!inputBio || !outputBio) {
        perror("Error opening input or output file");
        BIO_free_all(inputBio);
        BIO_free_all(outputBio);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    BIO *cipherBio = BIO_new(BIO_f_cipher());
    if (!cipherBio) {
        handleErrors();
    }

    // Imposta l'algoritmo di cifratura AES-256-CBC con chiave e IV fissi (DA CAMBIARE IN AMBIENTI REALI)
    BIO_set_cipher(cipherBio, EVP_aes_256_cbc(), (unsigned char *)"01234567890123456789012345678901", (unsigned char *)"0123456789012345", 0); // Modalità decifratura

    // Collega i BIO
    BIO_push(cipherBio, outputBio);
    BIO_push(cipherBio, inputBio);

    char buffer[INBUFSIZE];
    int bytesRead, decBytes, totalDecBytes = 0;

    // Leggi i dati cifrati dal BIO crittografico
    while ((bytesRead = BIO_read(cipherBio, buffer, sizeof(buffer))) > 0) {
        // Rimuovi il padding solo quando si legge l'ultimo blocco di dati
        if (BIO_pending(cipherBio) == 0) {
            if (!removePKCS7Padding(buffer, EVP_CIPHER_block_size(EVP_aes_256_cbc()), &bytesRead)) {
                handleErrors();
            }
        }

        // Scrivi i dati decifrati nel BIO di output
        decBytes = BIO_write(outputBio, buffer, bytesRead);
        if (decBytes <= 0) {
            handleErrors();
        }
        totalDecBytes += decBytes;
    }

    printf("Decryption complete. Total decrypted bytes: %d\n", totalDecBytes);

    BIO_free_all(inputBio);
    BIO_free_all(cipherBio);
}

int main(void) {
    OpenSSL_add_all_algorithms();
    ERR_load_BIO_strings();

    // Decifra i dati da un file di input criptato e li scrive su un file di output
    decryptAndWriteToFile("encrypted_output2.bin", "decrypted_output2.txt");

    EVP_cleanup();
    ERR_free_strings();

    return 0;
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using a debugger to see where the segmentation fault is coming from. You can also use a tool like valgrind. It will show you the line that causes the segmentation fault.

Comment: You're chaining one `cipherBio` into both your `inputBio` **and** your `outputBio`???